# Git Alias to Create Aliases

Tags: bash, git, alias

so I have a git alias called makealias that is set to the following:

```
!f() { git config --global alias.$1 '!f(){ $2;};f';}; f
```

When I run the command, I usually run it with something like this:

```
git makealias "testalias" "echo 'hello world'"
```

make alias successfully creates a new alias, but it doesnt bring the echo statement along for the ride.  When I run my command to see the text of my aliases, i find that testalias looks like this:

```
!f(){ $2;};f
```

What do I need to do differently so that when I run `git makealias "testalias" "echo 'hello world'"` the newly created command of testalias will be `!f(){ echo 'hello world';};f`

Comment: Remember that the shell won't expand variables inside single quotes (compare `echo '$HOME`' with `echo "$HOME"`).

Comment: See quite a few useful aliases at gitalias.com. Aliases to add and list aliases are at https://github.com/GitAlias/gitalias/blob/db8e868077fdecd3be1e1e7091a8578e032a1aa9/gitalias.txt#L364. Full disclosure: I'm a contributor.